# c++ thread create/delete vs thread stop/resume

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, condition-variable

I am writing application that use just 1 thread(except main thread). the thread lives only short time like 50ms. but, it should happen multiple times per second. and other than the activation time, the thread should be  stopped, and main thread should be running.

for example 50ms thead do something -> 20ms main do something -> 50ms thread something -> 20ms main do nothing ....

I first thought thread resume/stop will be good. but, is it better than thread create/destroy ? like thread create -> thread delete -> thread create -> thread delete ......

when I use thread creation/destroy strategy, I used thread constructor and thread.join() to finish and 1 atomic variable to know when to finish.

when I use thread resume/stop strategy, I used conditional_variable , mutex and condition_variable.wait().

I expected thread resume/stop strategy has better performance.
but, it doesn't look like that.  it looks like both have almost same performance and memory/cpu usage.

Comment: Not every routine/function/method/operator has a tag. Please choose tags from a list & read their wikis. Tag [tag:join] is for the relational DB operator.

Comment: Better use the latter approach. Thread creation is an expensive operation so it's better to use the second approach.

Comment: I'd also expect keeping the thread around to be less effort, but perhaps the runtime isn't giving you a new thread each time. It could have a threadpool hidden in the deepdark and is simply reusing the same threads over and over without telling you.

Comment: Every application has at least one thread, it's the one that executes `main()`. I guess with your first paragraph you want to say that you start an additional thread, right?

Comment: @Ulrich  yes, including main thread, there are 2 threads total.

Comment: You can [edit] your question to clarify that. A question where you don't have to collect different pieces of info from comments is much better.

Comment: You can monitor your thread with while(true) and make it sleep when you don't need that thread until the next task.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a thread on OS level usually indeed requires quite some overhead. But creating a std::thread object is not necessarily the same. The latter action might consist of only requesting a thread from a thread pool, and destruction of returning the thread back, while the OS thread themselves never cease to exist.

In such a scenario, you won't see much difference between the two approaches, as all that really is done (on OS level) is adding the thread to the thread scheduling algorithm and remove it from in both cases (unless the pool runs out of threads and needs to create new ones on OS level, too). The little differences that still might exist are probably smaller than the times the threads have to wait for a CPU core, as on a typical modern OS, you have many more threads than cores, so you probably won't be able to notice any differences at all.

Still just pausing resuming a thread is preferrable. You do not *rely* on a thread pool to be equally performant, and if you port your code to some OS that doesn't use one (or has it switched off), then you still (kind of) maintain your own thread pool that way...